# PostgreSQL idle queries, why doesn't the close method kill them? (ruby adapter)

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I am seeing a ton of idle queries in psql in the pg_stat_activity table. I am using the Ruby adapter, and creating a new connection every time. But after the query has been run, I close the connection by calling the `close` or `finish` method. But I still see a lot of idle queries.

I know idle queries are actually idle processes spun by PG, but I can't find any source explicitly saying this is a bad thing. Some answers on SO suggest that the best way to deal with this is using a cron job to kill the idle process.

Is that the right way do it? Why doesn't the `close` method kill the process?